# Flutter chat list update rebuild efficiency

Tags: flutter, chat, rebuild

I'm new to Flutter and I'm trying to build a chat application and I've watched several tutorials. To view the chat messages list/history, almost every tutorial is doing something like this: (I'm shortening the code to get to the point)

```
List<Widget> messages = api.listOfMessages();

return Column(children: messages);
```

Now every time there's a new message, `messages` is updated and the column is re-built. I gotta say the word "rebuild" sounds an expensive procedure to me. Say 2 users have been chatting 500 lines. Now every time a new message is coming, 500 lines are getting rebuilt over an over.

I thought about putting an empty widget at the end of the list. So when a new message arrives, I just insert it to that empty widget and have that to rebuild only:

```
List<Widget> messages = api.listOfMessages();

return Column(children: [...messages, EmptyWidgetForNewMessage()];
```

But that looks like a hack and will cause a lot of nested widgets, because every new message must also insert another EmptyWidget etc...

How can I avoid rebuilding previous messages and only insert the new one to the view? (or rebuilding the entire list is not that big a deal?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use sliver widget to build the messages that are visible in viewport(or within cacheExtent).
Like `ListView.build`, `ListView.separated`, from the doc of `ListView.build`:

> if the list view's children are
> created in advance, or all at once when the [ListView] itself is created,
> it is more efficient to use the [ListView] constructor. Even more efficient, however, is to create the instances on demand using this constructor's `itemBuilder` callback.

Also, we will not fetch all messages from server at once. Instead we will fetch them in batches with query like `?page=1&size=20`.

Note: There is a known issue with this widget, avoid using `shrinkWrap: true` if possible. See [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26072)

Answer (score 1):

couple of improvements that you could target

1. Use `ListView` builder constructor instead of the column, only the children widget that are currently visible in the screen will be rendered whereas in `Column` widget all of its children will be rendered. Also `ListView` should be your preferred widget, because the `Column` widget is not scrollable, and there are chances of overflow exception, if the message list length is huge.
2. Use `const` constructor for all type of widgets returned by  `api.listOfMessages()`, this will allow the compiler to reuse any rendered widget, meaning every time when a state change happens(in you case arrival of a new message) the entire tree is not re-rendered, the renderer will have the luxury of re using previously built message widget.

These two suggestions should take care of any performance bottlenecks, in short we would be rendering only the visible children widgets with ListView and we will be re reusing already rendered widget with the help of `const` constructor.